# How can I get what the input is to be all capital or lower case. No matter how I try it .lower() etc. my game stops working. Thanks in advance

Tags: python, uppercase, lowercase

```
def rooms_movement (location, direction): # making a function for room movement
    new_location = location  # defining a new variable that is equal to start point
    for l in rooms: # setting l as variable in rooms
        if l == location:  # making a nested loop inside the for loop
            if direction in rooms[l]:  # saying that the direction will come out of rooms dic
                new_location = rooms[l][direction]  # this is how i will call up movement and location from the gameplay
    return new_location


room_movement = rooms


def get_item(location):
    return rooms[location]['Item']


def game_play():  # instructions

    print('Welcome to the "COOLEST GAME!" ')
    print('The beginning of this epic journey starts in the galley.')
    print('To move between rooms type go North, go South, go East, and go West.')
    print('You must acquire a total of 8 separate items.')
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'\n")
game_play()
Inventory = []
items = ['Laptop', 'Mouse', 'Apple', 'Underwear', 'Puppy', 'Microchip', 'Cell Phone', 'Coded Instructions']


while True:
    print("The room you're in is the: ",  location)  # printing location which in this case is the galley
    print('Inventory: ', Inventory)
    item = get_item(location)

    print('You see a ', item)
    print('--------------------')
    direction = input("Type the direction you would like to move or type exit or get item: ")  # user input of direction

    #direction = direction.lower()   # ensuring that we can use capital and lower case letters as python is case sensitive
    print('----------------------------\n')  # keeping parts of the print more neat
    if (direction.lower() == 'Exit'):  # part of code where user can exit
        print(' *  * ')  # me trying to have fun after hours of trying to figure all of this out
        print('******')
        print('    v   "Bye!!!"')
        exit(0)  # built in exit in python
# next if loop is stating the cardinal direction will come from room movement and have location and direction
    if direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go South' or direction == 'go East':
        direction = direction[3:]
        new_location = rooms_movement(location, direction)
        if new_location == location:  # saying that if the new location is the same as location
            print("Error, there is a wall... ouch!\n")  # print this because you can't go that way
            print('----------------------------\n')  # keeping game neat

        else:
            location = new_location
    if direction == str('get ' + item):
        if item in Inventory:
            print('Item already taken, go to another room!!')
        else:
            Inventory.append(item)

    if len(Inventory) == 8:
        print('Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the Robot')
        print(' *  * ')  # me trying to have fun after hours of trying to figure all of this out
        print('******')
        print('    v   "Bye!!!"')
        exit(0)  # built in exit in python

    elif len(Inventory) != 8 and new_location == 'Basement':
        print("You haven't collected all of the items before entering the basement!! \n")
        print("Game Over")
        print("Please restart and try again")
        exit(0)
```

Comment: You have capital letters in the values you're comparing the lowercase string to

Answer (score 0):

After using `.lower()` your string only consists of lowercase characters. So if you want to check if it equals 'go North' it no longer works. Try to compare it to lowercase values.

```
if direction == 'go north'
```

Comment: I just want whoever is trying the game to be able to write go north GO NORTH, go North etc.

Comment: Yes, thats still possible